# liquabase command generateChangeLog generate java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: liquibase

I would like to generate csv files and loaddata changeset for some tables.

I use this command line:

```
$LB_HOME/liquibase --logLevel=DEBUG --changeLogFile=${TABLE}.xml \
--url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@local:1521/ORCL --username=TEST --password=TEST \
--dataOutputDirectory=csv --diffTypes=data \
--includeObjects="table:$TABLE" generateChangeLog
```

After a very long list of lines like this:

> DEBUG [liquibase.util.DependencyUtil$DependencyGraph]:
> Potential StackOverflowException. Pro-actively removing  with  incoming nodes

I get this error:

> ERROR [liquibase.integration.commandline.Main]: Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unknown reason
> java.lang.StackOverflowError: null

I put includeObjects="table:$TABLE" with only one table, why liquibase reads all object dependencies?
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

As per Liquibase Documentation, includeObjects is not valid parameter

here is the Link: https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/generatechangelog.html

Can you try running just generateChangeLog command without data and see if it works first?

Comment: Starting Liquibase at Fri, 13 Nov 2020 14:57:42 CET (version 3.10.3 #32 built at Mon Oct 12 07:24:42 UTC 2020)
14:57:43.176 INFO  [liquibase.command.core.GenerateChangeLogCommand]: BEST PRACTICE: The changelog generated by diffChangeLog/generateChangeLog should be inspected for correctness and completeness before being deployed
15:05:35.437 ERROR [liquibase.integration.commandline.Main]: Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unknown reason
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
        at liquibase.util.DependencyUtil$DependencyGraph.recursiveSizeDepth(DependencyUtil.java:142)